# Extract specific file from tar and copy it to custom folder without hierarchy

Tags: linux, wget, tar

I am executing following command in console:

```
wget -qO- https://dl.k8s.io/v1.6.1/kubernetes-client-linux-amd64.tar.gz | tar xvz -C ~/kubectl_folder/kubefile kubernetes/client/bin/kubectl
```

This command is basically downloading tar file and copying kubectl file in `~/kubectl_folder/kubefile` location with its previous hierarchy i.e. `kubernetes/client/bin` as expected

Thus the original hierarchy is:

```
~/kubectl_folder/kubefile/kubernetes/client/bin/kubectl
```

I wanted my file should be only copied inside `kubefile` folder as follows:

```
~/kubectl_folder/kubefile/kubectl
```

How can i achieve the same?

Comment: I don't think you can do this within one command. What's wrong with adding an extra pipe?

Comment: @Dominique nothing is wrong just i am trying to brainstorm and explore the more ways in which this can be used.